# How to serialise structs into io::Write in a loop

Tags: json, rust, stream, streaming, serde

I need to do a simple read/process/write in Rust like this:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct Incoming {
    first: String,
    last: String,
}

#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
struct Outgoing {
    name: String,
}

// Keep the read/write traits as generic as possible
fn stream_things<R: std::io::Read, W: std::io::Write>(reader: R, writer: W) {
    let incoming: Vec<Incoming> = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();

    for a in incoming {
        let b = Outgoing {
            name: format!("{} {}", a.first, a.last),
        };
        serde_json::to_writer(writer, &b).unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    stream_things(std::io::stdin(), std::io::stdout());
}
```

This does not compile because:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `writer`
  --> src/main.rs:20:31
   |
13 | fn stream_things<R: std::io::Read, W: std::io::Write>(reader: R, writer: W) {
   |                                    --                            ------ move occurs because `writer` has type `W`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                                    |
   |                                    help: consider further restricting this bound: `W: Copy +`
...
20 |         serde_json::to_writer(writer, &b).unwrap();
   |                               ^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

What is the correct way to write to `std::io::Write` in a loop?
Also how to correctly do it with serde's `to_writer`?

See the [plaground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=371ff6891de26fe9aecfcb05491c67cd).

Comment: You begin to understand rust when you realize that `self` can be a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `W` is `io::Write`, then [`&mut W`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-17) is also `io::Write`:

> `impl<'_, W: Write + ?Sized> Write for &'_ mut W`

so the following compiles:

```
fn stream_things<R: std::io::Read, W: std::io::Write>(reader: R, mut writer: W) {
    let incoming: Vec<Incoming> = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();

    for a in incoming {
        let b = Outgoing {
            name: format!("{} {}", a.first, a.last),
        };
        serde_json::to_writer(&mut writer, &b).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind me asking how you got to the `&mut` from that error message? Would never occur to me.

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak nothing specially really. Using a value by itself will consume it, whereas by its reference or mutable reference will not. Reading any Rust API signature, that's one thing dictates how it is intended to be used.